# Google Tag Manager, loaded via https, loads external scripts by http. How to avoid it ?

Tags: security, https, google-tag-manager

I load GTM by script https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=xxxxxx.

GTM after that loads this external script:
[image]

Chrome shows this warning (insecure content is blocked) in the address bar.
[image]

Moreover:
The link of the external script doesn't work: "Could not resolve host: track.mixtarget.ru".

How to avoid this problem, cause we don't want to have any insecure scripts on our site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, use secured external scripts only i.e. ending with https. This is a common problem and would persist as Google products(Chrome) are moving towards https connection only.

Second, track.mixtarget.ru should resolve to a valid host i.e. Each time the Google Tag Manager script executes, an HTTP Response is expected.

Hope this helps